How to make a HTML input be possible to change by a slider and manual input (keyboard)
I want to make an input that can be changed by a slider and by manual input, just like a regular <input type="number">. It has to be the same input because of JavaScript.
For example, here is the code I wrote:


const mph_in = document.getElementById("mph");
const dec_in = document.getElementById("dec");
const t_in = document.getElementById("t");
const out = document.getElementById("out");

mph_in.addEventListener('input', main);
dec_in.addEventListener('input', main);
t_in.addEventListener('input', main);


console.log(mph);

function m2mi(metre){
    return metre/1609.344;

}

function main(){

    // mph = 75.0;
    // dec = 0.9;
    // t = 1.0;


    mph = parseFloat(mph_in.value);
    dec = parseFloat(dec_in.value);
    t = parseFloat(t_in.value);

    v = mph*(1609.344/3600);

    reaction = t * v;

    braking = (v*v)/(2*dec);

    s = reaction + braking;

    console.log("main loaded");
    console.log("reaction distance: "+reaction);

    out.innerHTML = "Reaction distance: "+m2mi(reaction)+" mi<br> Braking distance: "+m2mi(braking)+" mi <br> <b>Stopping distance: "+m2mi(s)+" mi </b>";

}

function test(){
    console.log(m2mi(2000));

    // console.log("v = "+v);
}
<!-- 
  Train speed [mph]: 
  <input type="number" name="mph" id="mph" placeholder="75" value="75">
  <br> 
-->

Train speed [mph]: 
<input type="range" id="mph" name="mph" min="0" max="125" value="75" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value"/>
<output></output>

<br>

Deceleration [m/s<sup>2</sup>]: 
<input type="number" name="dec" id="dec" placeholder="0.9" value="0.9">

<br>

Reaction time [s]: <input type="number" name="t" id="t" placeholder="3" value="3">
<br>
    
<button onclick="main()">Calculate</button><br>
<button onclick="test()">Debug</button><br>
<span id="out" >[output]</span>



The code works as intended, except the fact that the speed can only be controlled by a slider (and I would want to make it controllable by manual input too, just like the other inputs) and the deceleration and reaction time also controllable by a slider (not only by manual input). Is there any way to do this?

Do you mean you will have three input tag on the page, and user can switch them between manual input and slider?

You can get current <input>'s name & value in change event, then update other <input>'s value which has same name.
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const update = ({ target }) => {
  const { name, value } = target;
  document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]`).forEach((input) => target !== input && (input.value = value));
};
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    update(e);
    main();
  });
});



const mph_in = document.getElementById("mph");
const dec_in = document.getElementById("dec");
const t_in = document.getElementById("t");
const out = document.getElementById("out");

function m2mi(metre) {
  return metre / 1609.344;
}

function main() {
  // mph = 75.0;
  // dec = 0.9;
  // t = 1.0;
  mph = parseFloat(mph_in.value);
  dec = parseFloat(dec_in.value);
  t = parseFloat(t_in.value);

  v = mph * (1609.344 / 3600);

  reaction = t * v;

  braking = (v * v) / (2 * dec);

  s = reaction + braking;

  console.log("main loaded");
  console.log("reaction distance: " + reaction);

  out.innerHTML = "Reaction distance: " + m2mi(reaction) + " mi<br> Braking distance: " + m2mi(braking) + " mi <br> <b>Stopping distance: " + m2mi(s) + " mi </b>";
}

function test() {
  console.log(m2mi(2000));
  // console.log("v = "+v);
}

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
const update = ({
  target
}) => {
  const {
    name,
    value
  } = target;
  document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]`).forEach((input) => target !== input && (input.value = value));
};
inputs.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    update(e);
    main();
  });
});
Train speed [mph]:<input type="number" id="mph" name="mph" min="0" max="125" value="75" placeholder="75">
<br> Train speed [mph]:<input type="range" id="mph-range" name="mph" min="0" max="125" value="75" />
<output></output>
<br> Deceleration [m/s<sup>2</sup>]:
<input type="number" name="dec" id="dec" placeholder="0.9" value="0.9">
<br> Reaction time [s]: <input type="number" name="t" id="t" placeholder="3" value="3">
<br>
<button onclick="main()">Calculate</button><br>
<button onclick="test()">Debug</button><br>
<span id="out">[output]</span>




You can try this way:
When you menual/slider input, the slider/menual input to auto update to the value.
You can try a custom event, or try Vue's v-modal(if you can use Vue). You can try change event.

Thank you for your response. Can you tell me how to do that? I tried to write code that will update the input but failed.

please create the input element first, then register to the DOM, use dom .onchange function, that will be working. If you have any issue please tell me.

Sorry, I don't understand what exactly I should write. Can you write an example code that does this?
